# How to get VMware XP online via Windows 7 host WIFI connection?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware, internet-connection

I have a **Windows 7 laptop** which is connected to the Internet via WIFI.

I have a **Windows XP virtual machine** running in VMware Player and would like it to connect to the Internet as well.

**How can I get my Windows XP VMWare machine to either share the connection with the Win7 host or make a new connection?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the network to **NAT** in order to connect it to the internet.

Open up the **VMWare Network Adapter Settings**.

[image]

Set the **Network Adapter** to **NAT**, to share the host IP address and gain access to the internet.

[image]