# How to transfer files between Win7-Host and WinXP-WMware machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, vmware

I have a **Win7 host** running a **WinXP VMware** machine which is [connected to the Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/298480/how-to-get-vmware-xp-online-via-windows-7-host-wifi-connection/298500#298500).

I would now like to be able to **transfer files** between these two machines.

This is the IP-info of the **WinXP VMware** machine:

[image]

And this is the IP-info of the **Win7 host**:

[image]

I can ping from the Win7-host to the WinXP-WMware machine:

[image]

**What is the easiest way now to transfer files between these two machines?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the built-in tool that VMware provides

> [Using Shared Folders](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html)
>
> With shared folders, you can easily share files among virtual machines and the host computer. To use shared folders, you must have the current version of VMware Tools installed in the guest operating system and you must configure your virtual machine settings to specify which directories are to be shared.

or you do the same as with any two computers connected to the net.

ftp-server, dropbox, network shares

Comment: I only have the player, not the workstation, so dropbox is the way for me, thanks for the idea. Here's a good youtube video on setting up Filezilla FTP Server though if anyone wants to go that route: http://youtu.be/IHnbnwPC5-0

Answer (score 0):

Another quick option is if you have installed VM-Ware tools on the client you can just drag and drop them between the two desktops.